# How to Pass Id correctly to Rest API Endpoint from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch data through endpoint from Django Rest Framework
endpoint is :

```
/api/v1/categories/nested/{id}/
```

Problem is when I'm requesting with id, Django server show this error :

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'undefined'.
[07/Feb/2022 15:53:01] "GET /api/v1/categories/nested/undefined/ HTTP/1.1" 500 162581
```

As this suggest I'm unable to Pass id correctly,
So need littl help to fix that
I'm using actions > reducer > store > component approach using react redux
action.js

```
export const listCategoryDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: CATEGORY_DETAIL_REQUEST });
  
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/categories/nested/${id}`); // Purpose to show nested brands[]
  
      dispatch({
        type: CATEGORY_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: CATEGORY_DETAIL_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.detail
            ? error.response.data.detail
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

reducer.js

```
export const categoryDetailsReducer = (
    state = { category: {  } },
    action
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case CATEGORY_DETAIL_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true, ...state };
  
      case CATEGORY_DETAIL_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, category: action.payload };
  
      case CATEGORY_DETAIL_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
  
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

store.js

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  categoryDetail: categoryDetailsReducer,
});
```

component

```
function CategoryDetail({ match, history }) {
    // const { id } = useParams();
    // console.log(id);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const categoryList = useSelector((state) => state.categoryList);
    const { loading, error, categories , page, pages} = categoryList;

    useEffect(() => {
        
        dispatch(listCategoryDetails());
    }, [dispatch, match]);

  return <div>
  
                {categories.map(category => (
                <Col key={category.id} sm={12} md={8} lg={4} xl={3} >
                  
                    <h1><strong>{category.title}</strong></h1>))}


</div>;
}

export default CategoryDetail;
```

Comment: yep.. you already defined the action to have parameter that accept an id.. just need to pass the id inside the function calls in the dispatch function.

Answer (score 2):

`const id = ...`
and pass it to dispatch function `dispatch(listCategoryDetails(id))`

Answer (score 1):

Before

```
// const { id } = useParams();
// console.log(id);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const categoryList = useSelector((state) => state.categoryList);
const { loading, error, categories , page, pages} = categoryList;

useEffect(() => {
    
    dispatch(listCategoryDetails());
}, [dispatch, match]);
```

After

```
const { id } = useParams();
console.log(id);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const categoryList = useSelector((state) => state.categoryList);
const { loading, error, categories , page, pages} = categoryList;

useEffect(() => {
    
    dispatch(listCategoryDetails(id));
}, [dispatch, match]);
```

Inside UseEffect You Are Not Passing `id` Variable So its Saying Id Is Undefined